# Pattern matching with different return types

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching

I'm learning F# and playing around with domain modeling using the type system.

In my very simplistic example, let's say we want to manage customers for a hotel. A customer can be in various states:

1. New Customer
2. Contact Information is defined.
3. The customer accepted GPDR.
4. The customer has checked in.

All these states are represented as different types. We also define that the customer is in "Pending" state as long as the customer has not checked in but has provided the contact information and/or has accepted GPDR:

```
type CustomerId = CustomerId of Guid
type ContactInformation = ContactInformation of string
type AcceptDate = AcceptDate of DateTime
type CheckInDate = CheckInDate of DateTime

type NewCustomer =
    private
        { Id: CustomerId }

type ContactOnlyCustomer =
    private
        { Id: CustomerId
          Contact: ContactInformation }

type AcceptedGdprCustomer =
    private
        { Id: CustomerId
          Contact: ContactInformation
          AcceptDate: AcceptDate }

type PendingCustomer =
    private
        | ContactOnly of ContactOnlyCustomer
        | AcceptedGdpr of AcceptedGdprCustomer  

type CheckedInCustomer =
    private
        { Id: CustomerId
          Contact: ContactInformation
          AcceptDate: AcceptDate
          CheckInDate: CheckInDate }    

type Customer =
    private
        | New of NewCustomer
        | Pending of PendingCustomer
        | CheckedIn of CheckedInCustomer
```

Now I want to update the contact information for a customer with the following function (no matter in which "state" the customer currently is):

```
let updateContact (customer: Customer) contact =
    match customer with
    | New c -> ContactOnly { Id = c.Id; Contact = contact }
    | Pending pending ->
        match pending with
        | ContactOnly c -> ContactOnly { c with Contact = contact }
        | AcceptedGdpr c -> AcceptedGdpr { c with Contact = contact }
    | CheckedIn c -> CheckedIn { c with Contact = contact } // <- Here I get a compile error saying that all branches must return the same type.
```

The problem here are the different types which are returned by the pattern matching expression. The `ContactOnly` and `AcceptedGdpr` union cases are of type `PendingCustomer` whereas the `CheckedIn` union case is of type `Customer`.

How to handle such a scenario? Basically, the `New` union case should transform the customer into a `ContactOnly` customer. All other cases (where the customer already has the contact information defined) should be updated with the new contact information.

---

What I've tried is to define the `Customer` type like this, i.e. move the `DetailsOnly` and `AcceptedGdpr` union cases directly to the `Customer` type:

```
type Customer =
    private
        | New of NewCustomer
        | ContactOnly of ContactOnlyCustomer
        | AcceptedGdpr of AcceptedGdprCustomer     
        | CheckedIn of CheckedInCustomer
```

With that I wouldn't need the nested pattern matching:

```
let updateDetails (customer: Customer) contact =
    match customer with
    | New c -> ContactOnly { Id = c.Id; Contact = contact }
    | ContactOnly c -> ContactOnly { c with Contact = contact }
    | AcceptedGdpr c -> AcceptedGdpr { c with Contact = contact }
    | CheckedIn c -> CheckedIn { c with Contact = contact }
```

This works, but this doesn't seem like the correct approach since this leads to duplication of type definitions when I still want to use the `PendingCustomer` type too for other functions.

As a F# beginner, I have the feeling that I'm missing a tiny simple thing here.

Comment: Could `updateContact` in the first example return a `Customer` as well and then you would have the same expression type in all branches.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer Yes, that is what I like to achieve. But I think I'm missing a technical detail here on how to do that. `ContactOnly` and `AcceptedGdpr` are just "subtypes" (`PendingCustomer`) of `Customer` but for the type system they are differernt, hence the compile error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by duplication of type definitions in this case. If you are referring to the repetition of fields in states, I wouldn't count that as duplication. It's not a problem as long as you keep it so simple that you don't see any gain in trying to do anything about it. Don't refactor prematurely - wait until you see there will be a gain. Then you will likely also more clearly see what needs doing. As for the nested type, that seems like a very poor way of modeling one particular route in your state diagram. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sympathetic to the idea of trying to use types to avoid illegal states especially when it comes to critical things like GDPR consents/contractual agreements.

After discussing a bit in the comments should `updateContact` update the contact info of a `Customer`?

```
let updateContact (customer: Customer) (contact : ContactInformation) : Customer =
    match customer with
    | New c -> ContactOnly { Id = c.Id; Contact = contact } |> Pending
    | Pending pending ->
        match pending with
        | ContactOnly c -> ContactOnly { c with Contact = contact } |> Pending
        | AcceptedGdpr c -> AcceptedGdpr { c with Contact = contact } |> Pending
    | CheckedIn c -> CheckedIn { c with Contact = contact }
```

In the original code `updateContact` return the contact info but not the updated customer leading to issues with finding an expression type that fits all branches. Here all branches yields a `Customer` avoiding the issue.

Comment: You might find the idea of lenses interesting, lenses are useful for updating nested values in immutable structures: https://medium.com/@heytherewill/functional-programming-optics-in-net-7e1998bfb47e

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify (such as extracting shared state) and make your cases a bit more explicit, this should make it easier to solve this problem.

```
type CustomerId = CustomerId of Guid
type ContactInformation = ContactInformation of string
type AcceptDate = AcceptDate of DateTime
type CheckInDate = CheckInDate of DateTime

type CheckedInCustomer =
    private
        { Contact: ContactInformation
          AcceptDate: AcceptDate
          CheckInDate: CheckInDate }    

type CustomerState =
    private
        | New
        | ContactOnly of ContactInformation
        | AcceptedGdpr of AcceptDate
        | ContactAndGdpr of ContactInformation * AcceptDate
        | CheckedIn of CheckedInCustomer

type Customer =
    private
        { Id: CustomerId
          State: CustomerState }

let updateContact (customer: Customer) contact =
    match customer.State with
    | New -> { customer with State = ContactOnly contact }
    | ContactOnly _ -> { customer with State = ContactOnly contact }
    | AcceptedGdpr acceptDate -> { customer with State = ContactAndGdpr(contact, acceptDate) }
    | ContactAndGdpr (_,acceptDate) -> { customer with State = ContactAndGdpr(contact, acceptDate) }
    | CheckedIn checkedIn -> { customer with State = CheckedIn { checkedIn with Contact = contact } }
```

Something you might also want to check out libraries such as [FSharp.Validationblocks](https://github.com/lfr/FSharp.ValidationBlocks) for making dealing with primitive type validation easier.

Answer (score -1):

I see no good reason to have such a complicated model. That doesn't mean there isn't one, but as far as what you've explained in the question, this seems to satisfy all your constraints while being significantly simpler:

```
type Customer =
  { Id: CustomerId
  , Contact: ContactInformation option
  , AcceptedGDPR: DateTime option
  , CheckedIn: DateTime option
  }

let updateDetails (customer: Customer) contact =
  { customer with Contact = contact }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason behind the "complicated" model is to model the domain logic with types, i.e. prevent invalid states with types. For example, customers can't check in as long as they haven't provided contact information and accepted GDPR. (I could define a `checkIn` function which only takes an `AcceptedGdprCustomer`)

Comment: You can easily prevent check-ins in invalid states just by having the transition function check the conditions and return an option. Maintaining invariants at runtime is usually not a good use for a static type system, as you seem to have discovered.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, @glennsl, and wonder whether you've missed something about the F# type system. And this is what I'm thinking about: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/

Comment: @BentTranberg I understand what they're trying to do, and think it's a good tool in certain cases, but it's a trade-off and there's nothing in the question that justifies the complexity and suggests it is the right tool in this case. You don't need static types to enforce business rules. That's what code is for. As long as you encapsulate it so that illegal states are only possible internally, it's not a problem. This seems more like the functional equivalent of `AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean` -- applying patterns mechanically just because you can, without thinking about actual needs.

Comment: That doesn't mean it is, but since the question isn't clear I'm offering an alternative that is a little bit out-of-the-box. Which I guess is offending to someone.

Comment: I don't see any reason why anyone should be offended. It's just that OP made it clear that the purpose was domain modeling using the type system, so this is no good answer.

Comment: Right, because a good shepherd would not ask questions or offer suggestions, but rather just continue to lead the sheep astray. Only if the sheep accidentally asks the right question should it bed led onto the right path. (Sorry about the sheep analogy. No offense intended, but it paints the right picture)